# Firebase : Method: projects.addFirebase of (google-apis-explorer) Api is not Working

Tags: firebase, google-apis-explorer

I am trying Firebase : **Method: projects.addFirebase** of (google-apis-explorer) Api. Where i pass the Request parameters : **projects/Projectid**.This project is exist in Google cloud provider But not in firebase.I want this project add in my firebase account.But when i try to test this api showing error like :

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

Here is Link:https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects/addFirebase?apix_params=%7B%22project%22%3A%22projects%2Fprojecttest%22%2C%22resource%22%3A%7B%7D%7D

[please check image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lja9Y.png)

Please help if i am doing anything wrong.
Thank you.

Comment: this question is barely programming related.

Comment: Hello @MartinZeitler. yes this barely programming related ,but if this api is working then i can try to access with programming.And Even i try to implement with code but not get any intellisense of this method: project.addfirebase. So that's why i try to check this api. It is bug or not i dnt know. thank you.

Comment: @commutiy did you manage to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for late posting, I've been using Apis Explorer myself and from what I see from the image you posted you didn't provide all the required parameters. They should be entered in section "Request body", after that it should work fine, provided you have the permission to invoke projects.addFirebase.

Update:

The paramteres you need to add to request body are: "timeZone" - timezone string like "Europe\Warsaw",  "regionCode" - two letters country abbrevation, for me it's PL,  "locationId" - location of the resources(string) you can find the list of locations [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/locations)

Comment: Hello and welcome!
While this does attempt to answer the question, can you please also add context/resources to help others who may stumble upon this?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @OneLunchMan I updated my answer, as you requested. Hope this will be enough to make things clearer.